# I cant install pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx

So I'm trying to install pyttsx3 and it says it is downloaded but when I go to import it says there is no module

```
C:\Users\gabri>pip install pyttsx3
Requirement already satisfied: pyttsx3 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.90)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (301)
Requirement already satisfied: comtypes in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (1.1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (223)
```

Here is the code

```
import pyttsx
calc = pyttsx3.init()
calc.say("Hi")
calc.runAndWait
```

here is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabri\Downloads\vc calculator.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyttsx3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
```

Comment: first of all type pip freeze and see if it is actually installed, if it is then try restarting your ide, or installing it from your ide directly

Comment: What does ```python -V``` show?

Comment: python -V shows Python 3.9.6

Comment: are you running python under a virtual environemt?